# Constructing a map of degree 2 $f:T^2\rightarrow S^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know the definition of degree and homology type stuff. But I don't know what a map $T^2\rightarrow S^2$ should actually *look* like. We never work with explicit examples in my class and I just have no idea what to *write*. Should I map toroidal coordinates to toroidal coordinates? If not, then what? How do I *build* this map explicitly? I know his is a stupid question but please help, I'm having trouble with the formalism and I need somebody to directly spell it out for me. Please show me what to do. I don't know how to easily describe maps between spaces like this or how to tell intuitively what I should do to make it have a particular degree. I get what this doing algebraically to the homology groups but I don't know what it is doing to the actual set.

Comment: A torus admit always a map $j:T\longrightarrow T$ which is an involution, that is $j^2=id_T$. So you can consider the quotient $T/j$ which is homeomorphic to a sphere.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the construction of the torus T as a square Q with some identifications on the boundary B. If you look at the image in T of the boundary of Q, you find two circles joined at a point. Call A the resulting subspace of T.

Now if you collapse A in T to a point to get the space T/A, you get the same thing as if you had collapsed the boundary B of the square Q to a point. That is, T/A is homeomorphic to Q/B, and this last space is a 2-sphere.

We get in this way a quotient map $f:T \to T/A\cong S^2$. This map has degree 1, as you can probably check.

Now if we identify $S^2$ with the extended complex plane, the map $q:z\mapsto z^2$ has degree 2.

The composition $q\circ f$ has degree 2.

Answer (score 1):

Take any degree 1 map $S^1\times S^1 \to S^2$, (e.g. the map $S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \wedge S^1=S^2$) and compose it with the map $S^2 \to RP^2 \to RP^2/RP^1=S^2$ which has degree 2.  This is a degree 2 map.

Comment: What is the second map??? I'm trying to be explicit, this isn't explicit at all

Comment: Yes it is.  There is a canonical covering projection from $S^2$ to $RP^2$.  There is the image of $RP^1$ in $RP^2$ of the map $[x:y] \mapsto [x:y:1] \in RP^2$, so there is a quotient map $RP^2/RP^1$.  The image of this map is the $1-$ skeleton of $RP^2$, so collapsing it gives an explicit homeomorphism with $S^2$.

Comment: For the map $S^2 \to RP^2 \to RP^2/RP^1=S^2$, on integral homology this must be $0$ not degree $2$ since it factors through $H_2(RP^2,\mathbb{Z})$ which is $0$.  Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: @AlgTop1854 I think you're correct. The map isn't of degree 2, it's of degree 0. Consider the northern and southern hemispheres of the domain $S^2$. One of them is mapped preserving orientation, and the other's is reversed since we're working in $S^2$. Thus the degree must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You want a map $f: S^1  \times S^1 \to S^2$ of degree two. It suffices to provide a map of degree one, since the map $z \times z^2$ is of degree two from the torus to the torus, and degree is functorial.

For a map of degree one, consider the smash product map

$$\gamma: S ^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \wedge S^1 \cong S^2.$$

To see that this has degree one, you can use the fact that cellular maps are determined by their degrees when collapsing subcomplexes. With the "standard" CW complex structure on $S^1 \times S^1$, $\gamma$ becomes the identity map on the non-collapsed $2$-cell.